# How to kill the PID of service that configured as Restart=always

Tags: rhel, systemd, services, kill, pkill

Dear friends and colleges ,

We have service under  `/etc/systemd/system`

Service name is `calc_live_servers.service`

Since  `Restart=always` is configured in   `calc_live_servers.service`

Then when we `kill` the `PID` of the process or `kill -9`  , then  service is restarted again and will be up

is it possible to kill the `PID` so service will not start again after we kill it in spite `Restart=always`?

The service `calc_live_servers.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=calc_servers Server
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitNOFILE=65535
Type=simple
User=CAS
Group=CAS
ExecStart=/usr/bin/calc_servers-start /etc/calc_servers/calc_servers.properties
ExecStop=/usr/bin/calc_servers-stop
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Main target -  is to stop the service by kill the PID without use `systemctl stop <SERVICE NAME >` and that because sometimes stopping the service not really stop it**

Answer (score 3):

Instead of killing PID, stop the service with `sudo systemctl stop calc_live_servers` - that is the way to stop a service. And if you don't want to have it running, disable the service with `sudo systemctl disable calc_live_servers`.

Comment: but as I said sometimes service not stopped , so this is the reason that we want to kill the PIS but after we kill it then service start again because Restart=always

Comment: Stop and kill then.

Comment: no so good in some case when I stop the service then pid will also killed before I killed it with kill command

Comment: you could `killall  process_name` or `ps ax | grep process_name OR pgrep process_name ` to find its PID.